# changing a function to use SHA256 hashing rather than SHA1 hashing

Tags: .net, powershell, sha1, sha256, sha2

Can someone kindly help me with the following question
I have the following function which works fine

```
function Decrypt-String($Encrypted, $Passphrase, $salt, $init) 
{ 
    if($Encrypted -is [string]){ 
        $Encrypted = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Encrypted) 
       } 

    $r = new-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged 
    $pass = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Passphrase) 
    $salt = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($salt) 
    $r.Key = (new-Object Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes $pass, $salt, "SHA1", 5).GetBytes(32) #256/8 
    $r.IV = (new-Object Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed).ComputeHash( [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($init) )[0..15] 

    $d = $r.CreateDecryptor() 
    $ms = new-Object IO.MemoryStream @(,$Encrypted) 
    $cs = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $ms,$d,"Read" 
    $sr = new-Object IO.StreamReader $cs 
    Write-Output $sr.ReadToEnd() 
    $sr.Close() 
    $cs.Close() 
    $ms.Close() 
    $r.Clear() 
}
```

There are two place in the code which reference SHA1

I want to switch to SHA256, although both the .NET classed above support SHA256 it throws the following error is I single change the bold text from SHA1 to SHA256

```
Exception calling "ReadToEnd" with "0" argument(s): "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."
At J:\UTemp\063146ee-175d-4a33-b485-7c6dd0e309f6.ps1:28 char:5
+     Write-Output $sr.ReadToEnd()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException

Exception calling "Close" with "0" argument(s): "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."
At J:\UTemp\063146ee-175d-4a33-b485-7c6dd0e309f6.ps1:29 char:5
+     $sr.Close()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException
```

Any assistance most welcome
Ernie

Comment: Always start by googling the error message, I see at least several answers for C# that seem to be applicable here since the .NET class is the same.

Comment: The key needs to be the same for encryption and decryption when you use a symmetric cipher (like Rijndael). Using `SHA256` for the key derivation function obviously results in a new key, hence the (somewhat cryptic) error. *Why* do you "want to switch to SHA256"? It's not going to increase the security of your function anyways

Comment: Hello all, thanks for taking the time to reply, sorry I did not reply sooner (I did not get an email informing me anyone had replied to my question). Please note in the first instance I am not a programmer but OK with scripting and understand the basics of .NET (Types, their methods etc.)

Comment: Hello all, thanks for taking the time to reply, 
The InfoSec department prefer SHA2 over SHA1. If I can explain security is not increased in this case using SHA2 (SHA256) hashing that would be great, can you please advise how do I point this out as to them? 
I see now (thanks), I need to update the encryption function to SHA256, then encrypt, then take the relevant data from their before passing to the decrypt function Duh!
Thanks again for everyone’s help
Ernie

Comment: Hello  Mathias, thanks for your input, yes if I now change the encryption to use SHA256 hashing then the updated decryption (also using SHA256) works. How I missed that I don't know Duh! thanks again Ernie